# ¿Cómo recorrer este JSON en PHP?

Tags: php, json

¿Cómo puedo recorrer este objeto JSON usando PHP?

Ejemplo de objeto JSON:

```
{
  "mensaje": "1 resultado(s)",
  "resultado": {
    "documentos": {
      "items": [
        {
          "nombreArchivo": "doci.pdf",
          "tamanoArchivo": 150,
          "pathArchivo": "/content/RESOLUCIONES/2019/02/19/10/19/file",
          "formulario": "RESOLUCIONES",
          "extracto": null,
          "idDocumento": "dc102ddf-b42e-493a-8c85-5baa34beead0",
          "paginasArchivo": 1,
          "archivoIndexadoPorUsuario": "root",
          "archivoIndexadoEnFecha": "19/02/2019 10:19:08",
          "valoresAtributos": [
            {
              "nombre": "Numero de Resolución",
              "valor": "12345",
              "tipo": "STRING"
            },
            {
              "nombre": "Tipo de Resolución",
              "valor": "Secretaria General",
              "tipo": "CATALOGO"
            },
            {
              "nombre": "Fecha",
              "valor": "19/02/2019",
              "tipo": "FECHA"
            },
            {
              "nombre": "Detalle",
              "valor": "prueba",
              "tipo": "TEXTO"
            },
            {
              "nombre": "Responsable",
              "valor": "prueba",
              "tipo": "STRING"
            },
            {
              "nombre": "Usuario",
              "valor": "prueba",
              "tipo": "STRING"
            },
            {
              "nombre": "workflow-state-changer",
              "valor": "root",
              "tipo": "STRING"
            },
            {
              "nombre": "workflow-state-date",
              "valor": "19/02/2019",
              "tipo": "FECHA"
            },
            {
              "nombre": "comentario",
              "valor": "Iniciado automáticamente en la indexación",
              "tipo": "TEXTO"
            },
            {
              "nombre": "document-state",
              "valor": "En Proceso",
              "tipo": "STRING"
            },
            {
              "nombre": "document-state-changer",
              "valor": "root",
              "tipo": "STRING"
            },
            {
              "nombre": "document-state-date",
              "valor": "19/02/2019",
              "tipo": "FECHA"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "totalDeItems": 1,
      "disponibles": 1,
      "tiempoDeEjecucion": 33,
      "inicio": 0,
      "cantidad": 10
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido user118367, deberías pasarte por el Centro de Ayuda y revisa [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). ¿Que has intentado hasta ahora? Deberías mostrar un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) o al menos demostrar que has intentado algo por tus propios medios.

Answer (score 2):

```
$json = <<<EOF
{
  "mensaje": "1 resultado(s)",
  "resultado": {
    "documentos": {
      "items": [
        { ...
EOF;

// Crea una estructura de standardObjects
$data = json_decode($json);

// Crea un array associativo
$data = json_decode($json, true);
```

Referencia:
http://php.net/json_decode

Luego es solo una cuestión de foreach's y $data['entrada']